# Global variables not defined in {% set %}

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following:

layout.html

```
{% if enableEntry or enableExit %}
  {% from "cp.layout.html" import entry, exit %}
{% endif %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    {% if enableEntry %}{{ entry }}{% endif %}
    {% if enableExit %}{{ exit }}{% endif %}

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

cp.layout.html

```
{% set entry %}
...
      {% if offer.text_id == "mcd" %}
      Mcdonald
      {% elif offer.text_id == "bk" %}
      Burger King 
      {% endif %}
...
{% endset %}
```

in my view:

```
def test(): 
  .... (offer is defined here) ...
  return render_template('layout.html', offer=offer)
```

I am getting an error that `UndefinedError: 'offer' is undefined`

Is there a way to pass variables that have global scope in the view to {% set %} blocs?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you never include your **test.html** under **layout.html**

I not sure is this help, this is my jinja 2 template design u can try

layout.html

```
{%- extends "test.html" %}
{# {% include "test.html" %} #}

{% block content %}
    {{ super() }}
{%- endblock %}
```

test.html

```
{% block content %} 
  <div>
    <h1>{{ offer }}</h1>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Let me know is this method work will give more explanation later

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough https://gist.github.com/vicngtor/2a0b1228899a179cecd013e2a7ee2a93 I am using from ... import